# Symfony forms: how to set default value for a textarea widget

Tags: html, forms, symfony1, textarea

I am using Symfony 1.3.2 on Ubuntu 9.10

I want to set the default value of a textarea widget, with data read froma  adb.

My code snippet in the template looks likes this:

```
<?php $form['notes']->render(); ?>
```

The API docs dont show how to do this - does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Did you look at this? http://forum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/64073/#msg_64073

Comment: Yes, I saw that post. I ignored it because it is a hack... I will have to manually reimplement all of my widgets and validators if I inherit from sfForm instead of the base object, which becomes a maintenance nightmare if the underlying model properties changes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this in your action or the form class:

```
$this->form = new yourForm(); // If its in your action

$text = // data for prepopulating field, from db or anywhere

$this->form->setDefault('notes', $text);
```

... or if you've got multiple fields:

```
$this->form->setDefaults(array('notes' => $text, 'more_notes' => $more_text));
```

Or if you prefer declaring it just once with the widget in your form class configuration (I think this is right):

```
$this->setWidgets(array(
  // widgets
  'notes' => new sfWidgetFormTextArea(array('default' => $text)),
  // widgets
));
```

Comment: Tom: Thanks! that did it (I have struggled with this problem)

Comment: How should one do the same thing for a single `TextareaType` field?